# Apache 2.4 timeout not working for idle connections?

Tags: apache-2.4, timeout, web, request

I have to lower the Apache Timeout value. I tried to make it 3 or 5. I opened a telnet connection to my Apache and left it with no data, it's always ~30sec + Apache Timeout.

I tested this configuration in Apache 2.2 and it works right (3 sec and the connection is closed automatically).
I tried to make an Apache 2.4 fresh install in a VPS, with no CGI and the less enabled modules I can with no success.

These are the modules I have: authz_core.load  authz_user.load  headers.load  mpm_prefork.conf  mpm_prefork.load

But, if you open the connection and send something (like the first line of the request) it runs fine and then Timeout apply successfully

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was the AcceptFilter configuration (new in 2.4). It defaults to "data" where Linux kernel doesn't tell Apache anything about the connection until there is some data on it.

To "solve" this just add into apache2.conf:
    AcceptFilter http none

or even
    AcceptFilter https none

So connections are passed directly to Apache. But there's no need to do this as connections are not being handled by Apache  yet.